# Evaluating $\int\frac{1}{(x-2)^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> I'm struggling with the integral, $$\int\frac{1}{(x-2)^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 2}}dx.$$

**I tried it as follows:**

Substituting $x-2 = \frac1t \implies dx = \frac{-dt}{t^2}.$
$$\therefore \int\frac{dx}{(x-2)^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 2}} = \int \frac{- dt}{\frac{t^2}{t^4} \sqrt{(\frac1t + 2)^2 + 6 (\frac1t + 2) + 2}} = \int \frac{-t^3}{\sqrt{18t^2 + 10t + 1}}\ dt$$

How to continue from here?

Comment: Just a thought: complete the square in the denominator for $18\left( t - \frac{5}{18} \right)^2 - \frac{7}{18}$ and use a secant substitution. I'm still working from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll also try.

Comment: @SeanRoberson shouldn't it be $18\left(t + \frac{5}{18}\right)^2 - \frac{7}{18}$?

Comment: After the substitution $t+ \frac{5}{18}  = \frac{\sqrt{7}}{18} \sec{\theta}$, I got $$\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{(7)^{1/4}5832}\int \left(-17\sqrt{17} \sec^4{\theta} + 255 \sec^3{\theta}- 75\sqrt{17} \sec^2\theta + 125 \sec{\theta}\right) \ d\theta$$
which  is easily integrable. I hope so my calculations are correct.

Comment: Yes, I copied incorrectly from WA.

Comment: Euler substitution works but it's quite long-winded , so I'm just going to mention this instead of writing an answer.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{355 \sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{-x+\sqrt{x (x+6)+2}+2}{3
   \sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{3 \sqrt{x (x+6)+2} (x (101 x-554)+920)}{(x-2)^3}}{34992}$$

Comment: `Integrate[1/((x - 2)^4*Sqrt[x^2 + 6 x + 2]), x] // 
  FullSimplify // Apart`    $\frac{25 \sqrt{x^2+6 x+2}}{1944 (x-2)^2}-\frac{101 \sqrt{x^2+6 x+2}}{11664 (x-2)}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6 x+2}}{54 (x-2)^3}+\frac{355 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{5 x+8}{3 \sqrt{2 x (x+6)+4}}\right)}{34992 \sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $y=x-2$ to rewrite the integral as

$$I_4= \int\frac{1}{(x-2)^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 2}}dx
=\int \frac{1}{y^4 \sqrt{y^2 + 10y + 18}}dy $$
and then integrate by parts to get the reduction formula
$$18(n-1)I_n=-\frac{\sqrt{y^2 + 10y + 18}}{y^{n-1}}-5(2n-3)I_{n-1}-(n-2)I_{n-2}
$$
Apply the formula three times to reduce it to
$$I_4=\frac1{54} \left(-\frac1{y^3} + \frac{25}{36y^2}-\frac{101}{216y}\right)\sqrt{y^2 + 10y + 18}-\frac{355}{11664}I_1
$$
where
$$I_1= \int\frac{1}{y \sqrt{y^2 + 10y + 18}}dy
=-\frac1{\sqrt{18}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{18}\sqrt{y^2 + 10y + 18} }{5y+18}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Continuing where you left off,

$$\begin{align*}
I &= - \int \frac{t^3}{\sqrt{18t^2+10t+1}} \, dt \\[1ex]
&= -16 \int \frac{(s-5)^3}{(s^2-18)^4} \, ds
\end{align*}$$

by employing the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution),

$$s = \frac{\sqrt{18t^2+10t+1}-1}t \implies t = \frac{2s-10}{18-s^2} \implies dt = \frac{2(18-10s+s^2)}{(18-s^2)^2} \, ds$$

The rest can be done by expanding into partial fractions.

---

Alternatively, starting over,

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{dx}{(x-2)^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 2}} \\[1ex]
&= \frac18 \int \frac{(1-y^2)^3}{\left(y^2+\sqrt2\,y-4\right)^4} \, dy \tag{1} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac1{4\sqrt2} \int \frac{(z^2-2)^3}{\left(z^2+2z-8\right)^4} \, dz \tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

and again with partial fractions.

---

- $(1)$ : substitute

$$y = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+2} - \sqrt2}{x} \implies x=\frac{2\sqrt2\,y-6}{1-y^2} \implies dx=\frac{2\left(\sqrt2\,y^2-6y+\sqrt2\right)}{(1-y^2)^2} \, dy$$

- $(2)$ : substitute $z=\sqrt2\,y$

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to continue from the last known position above. In the end, you'll get a polynomial in secants, which just results in using standard tricks from calculus II (along with integration by parts).

Let's start with the standard secant substitution $t + \frac{5}{18} = \sqrt{\frac{7}{18}} \sec y,$ so $dt = \sqrt{\frac{7}{18}} \sec y \tan y \ dy.$ Our integral becomes

$$ \int \frac{-t^3}{\sqrt{18t^2 + 10t + 1}}\ dt = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} \int \frac{ \left( \sqrt{\frac{7}{18}} \sec y - \frac{5}{18} \right)^3 \left( \sqrt{\frac{7}{18}} \sec y \tan y \ dy \right)}{\sqrt{\frac{7}{18}} \tan y}$$

and thankfully the stuff in the denominator cancels. This leaves

$$ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} \int \left( \sqrt{\frac{7}{18}} \sec y - \frac{5}{18} \right)^3 \sec y \ dy. $$

It gets quite messy, but after expanding the binomial, we get

$$ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} \int a^3 \sec^4 y - 3a^2 b \sec^3 y + 3ab^2 \sec^2 y -b^3 \sec y \ dy$$

where I've relabeled $a = \sqrt{\frac{7}{18}}$ and $b = \frac{5}{18}$ to make things cleaner. The first term is handled with the substitution $z = \tan y$ (after pulling two secants - again, standard calculus II technique), the second using integration by parts (choose $u = \sec y, \ dv = \sec^2 y \ dy$), and the third and fourth are standard results. I won't flesh out all the details here, but we obtain:

$$ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} \left( \frac{a^3 \tan^3 y}{3} + a^3\tan y - \frac{3a^2 b}{2} \left( \ln |\sec y + \tan y| + \sec y \ \tan y \right) \\ + 3ab^2 \tan y - b^3 \ln |\sec y + \tan y| \right) + C $$

(wow!). We're almost home free. By drawing a triangle based on our secant substitution, we obtain $\tan y = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} \left( t - b \right)^2 - 1}.$ Finally, invert your initial substitution to get $t = \frac{1}{x-2}.$

Now, by being lazy (sorry!), we arrive at our result:

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} \frac{\left( a \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{x-2} - b \right)^2 - 1} \right)^3}{3} + a^3 \left(\sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{x-2} - b \right)^2 - 1} \right) - \frac{3a^2 b}{2} \left( \ln \left( \frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{1}{x-2} - b \right) + \left( \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{x-2} - b \right)^2 - 1} \right) \right) + \left( \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{x-2} - b \right)^2 - 1} \right)  \frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{1}{x-2} - b \right) \right) + 3b^2 \left(\frac{1}{x-2} - b \right) - b^3 \ln \left| \left( \frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{1}{x-2} - b \right) + \left( \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{x-2} - b \right)^2 - 1} \right) \right) \right| + C$$

Wow! I may have mismatched some parentheses here, but that's a result.